# Removing rows containing specific string value when a number of conditions are met (pandas)

Tags: pandas

If I have the following dataframe:

```
df = """
    doc_id      source     sentence_number  Species   Valve   Fretindex
1  33075059515  AAP_news   2                fish      30x          SAR
2  33075059515  AAP_news   2                snapper   30x          SAR
3  53075235984  Goa Herald 5                fish      50y          SAR
4  28865465787  Bulletin   4                turtle    50y          SAR
5  28865465787  Bulletin   4                shark     50y          NaN
6  28865465787  Bulletin   3                fish      NaN          SAR
7  87652548931  Bulletin   1                fish      NaN          NaN
8  87652548931  Bulletin   1                turtle    NaN          NaN
```

How can I remove all the rows containing value 'fish' for the column 'Species' IF there is a different value for 'Species' (e.g., snapper, shark or other) in another row with the same values for doc_id, sentence_number, Valve and Fretindex?

I tried different versions of the duplicate function and drop.duplicates in pandas such as the following code:

```
result = df[((result1.duplicated(subset = ["doc_id", "sentence_number", "Valve", "Fretindex"], keep=False)) & 
         (df['SPECIES'] == df['fish'] )
        ~df.duplicated(subset = ["doc_id", "sentence_number", "Valve", "Fretindex"], keep=False)]
```

However it is not giving the correct output. What I would like to achieve:

```
df = """
    doc_id      source     sentence_number  Species   Valve   Fretindex
2  33075059515  AAP_news   2                snapper   30x          SAR
3  53075235984  Goa Herald 5                fish      50y          SAR
4  28865465787  Bulletin   4                turtle    50y          SAR
5  28865465787  Bulletin   4                shark     50y          NaN
6  28865465787  Bulletin   3                fish      NaN          SAR
8  87652548931  Bulletin   1                turtle    NaN          NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is one way to get the desired result:

```
df.drop(df[(df["doc_id"].isin(list(df[(df[['doc_id', 'sentence_number', 'Valve', 'Fretindex']].duplicated())].doc_id))) & (df["Species"] == "fish")].index)
```

You get the `doc_id` of the rows that matched `duplicated()` call for columns  doc_id, sentence_number, Valve and Fretindex. Then filter the df with an `isin` with the doc ids you recently got. Finally, check if the `Species` column contains `fish` and `drop` those entries.

You mentioned that you wanted to keep duplicate entries that only contained `fish` as their species. You can do that with adding `drop_duplicates` to the query above:

```
df.drop(df[(df["doc_id"].isin(list(df[(df[['doc_id', 'sentence_number', 'Valve', 'Fretindex']].duplicated())].doc_id))) & (df["Species"] == "fish")].drop_duplicates(keep=False).index)
```